# Why does my restarted Java program lose keyboard focus?

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder, shutdown-hook

I attempted to create a simplified failsafe Java application that would restart itself, whenever it was forcibly shutdown (in Windows, using CMD command of CTRL+C ).

The batch code looks like this :

```batch
@echo off
setlocal

start /wait java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow

if errorlevel 1 goto retry
echo Finished successfully
exit

:retry
echo retrying...
start /wait java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow
```

And the java code is this one :

```
public class WakeMeUpSomehow {
    static class Message extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {

                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello World from run");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to clarify my understanding . I think that because Java runs within a JVM environment, then it has some limitations in regards to restarting a JVM which was forcibly closed down (if we restart a forcibly-shutdown JVM via a batch file, then it loses the cursor-focus  and it just runs in a new CMD window that cannot have keyboard focus.

My goal was to have this app keep running in a loop (a la "digital wackamole" ), but I can only ever re-run it once (where it's running in a non-responsive CMD window )

Someone had suggested that I look at Apache Daemon tool, but I'm not sure how this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an endless loop in case of errorlevel 1 and above add a label before the `start` line:

```
:run
start /wait java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow
if errorlevel 1 echo retrying... & goto run
echo Finished successfully
```

However this will also open a new window, so if you want to restart the `java` process in the already started window you may use `typeperf` to check its CPU usage (so that you can forcibly close the process and restart it) or simply start `java` anew once the execution is returned into the batch file.

- In case the `java` process exits (doesn't hang) we can detect it with `tasklist`:

  ```
  :run
      start java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow
  :check
      timeout 1 >nul
      tasklist /fi "imagename eq java.exe" | find "java.exe" >nul
      if errorlevel 1 echo retrying... & goto run
      goto check
  ```
- In case the `java` process hangs and the CPU usage is 0% for 1 minute:

  ```
  if not "%~1"=="childprocess" goto main
  :loop
      java BatchWakeMeUpSomehow
      goto loop

  :main
      start "" "%~dpnx0" childprocess
  :check
      for /f "skip=2 delims=, tokens=2" %%a in ('
          typeperf "\process(java)\%% processor time" -sc 1 -si 60
      ') do if %%a=="0.000000" taskkill /f /im java.exe
      goto check
  ```

Comment: thanks very much ! I'll be studying this one, as it's not very clear at the moment